# Better upper bound for $\frac{\prod_{k = -n}^n (m +k)}{(m-1)^{2n +1}}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

For  $m, n$  two integers satisfying $m > n \geq 1,$ define
$$P(n, m) := \frac{\prod_{k = -n}^n (m +k)}{(m-1)^{2n +1}}.$$

I wand to find an estimate for $P(n,m)$ where the r.h.s doesn't depend on $m.$

I used the AM–GM inequality, so that
$$\sqrt[2n+1]{\prod_{k = -n}^n (m +k)} \leq \frac{\sum_{k = -n}^n (m +k)}{2n+1} = m.$$
Thus we have $$P(n,m) \leq \left(\frac{m}{m-1}\right)^{2n+1}\leq  \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{2n+1} = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n+1}=:a_n\,.$$
It seems that $a_n$ decreases from $a_1 = 8$ to $a_\infty = e^2.$ However,  I found, by plotting $m\mapsto P(m,n)$ for many values of $n$ that
$$P(n, m)\leq 6, \forall\, m >n \geq 1$$
which is better than the above estimate.
I'd be grateful for any hint to prove such estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\eqalign{
  & P(n,m) = {{\prod\limits_{k =  - n}^n {\left( {m + k} \right)} } \over {\left( {m - 1} \right)^{\,2n + 1} }}
 = {{m\prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {m^{\,2}  - k^{\,2} } \right)} } \over {\left( {m - 1} \right)^{\,2n + 1} }} =   \cr 
  &  = {{m^{\,2n + 1} \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {1 - {{k^{\,2} } \over {m^{\,2} }}} \right)} }
 \over {\left( {m - 1} \right)^{\,2n + 1} }} = \left( {1 + {1 \over {m - 1}}} \right)^{\,2n + 1}
 \prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {1 - {{k^{\,2} } \over {m^{\,2} }}} \right)}  \cr} 
$$
and take the log and put minimum $m=2$

Comment: I don't see how  taking the log would help. In other words, why does the r.h.s in your statement reach the maximum at $(m =2, n =1)$ ?